# Missing argument 1 for search_model::autocomplete(),

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

This is the  controller  search.php

```
public function login()
{
    $email=$this->input->post('email');
    $password=md5($this->input->post('password'));
    $result=$this->search_model->login($email,$password);   
    if(!$result) {
        $this->index();

    }

    else        {
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$email);
        $seid=$this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $data['result'] =$this->search_model->autocomplete();              
        $this->load->view('pagination_view',array('result' => $result));    
    }

}
```

===========================Model=========================================

```
public function autocomplete($like) {

    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('tbl_reg');
    $this->db->like('name', $like);
   // $this->db->where('status', ACTIVE);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result();
    }
}
```

in controller search.php what argument is added to the `autocomplete()`. the code is

```
$data['result'] = $this->search_model->autocomplete();
```

I got an error like this  Severity: Warning

> Message: Missing argument 1 for search_model::autocomplete(),
>
> and  another error message like
>
> ```
> Undefined variable: like
> ```

Whats the solution for this problem?

Comment: You need to accept an answer by clicking the checkmark

Comment: @Amy pass $like variable to ur  $data['result'] =$this->search_model->autocomplete();

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass argument in your model function

```
$this->search_model->autocomplete($YOUR_LIKE_VARIABLE);// pass your like variable here
```

Because in model file you use

```
public function autocomplete($like) {
```

Comment: @Santy    what  is the  'YOUR_LIKE_VARIABLE   means??

Comment: The variable you want to pass in your model file for like. I mean `$like`

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to pass the like variable as argument to your model function

In your controllers

```
$like = "matching word"; // replace this with your value;
$data['result'] =$this->search_model->autocomplete($like);
```

Comment: $like = "matching word"; // replace this with your value;
$data['result'] =$this->search_model->autocomplete($like);

Answer (score 0):

If you not passing $like variable then How your model will search.

```
$like='any text' // this would be your keyword for which you are doing auto complete process, Like any name or anything.
$data['result'] = $this->search_model->autocomplete($like);
```